# How to determine media completion in VideoCastControllerActivity?

Tags: android, chromecast

In my app, I am using the CastCompanionLibrary to cast videos to a chromecast device. I want to perform some action when the video has finished playing. How do I determine as to when the video has completed playing? I did not find any suitable callback for this.

Comment: Are you playing a queue or just a single item?

Comment: I am playing just a single item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Register a VideoCastConsumer that implements `onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated()`. This will inform you when the playback status changes.
2. In that callback, get the `mediaStatus = mCastManager.getMediaStatus()`; this will give you the updated status.
3. If `mediaStatus == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_IDLE` and `mCastManager.getIdleReason() == MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_FINISHED`, then it means the currently playing item is just finished.

Note that a version of this is already being done in the associated fragment so please tell us what you are doing exactly; what I suggested allows you to generically find out when the playback of a single media items reaches its end.